# .Net Core Async File Result

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.Net Core the reccommended way for returning files is to gain access through the `PhysicalFileProvider` this provides additional security including scoping all paths to a directory and its children.  Currently my entire application is Async and I would like for all of my methods to remain so.

```
public static string BASE_PATH = Path.GetTempPath();
public static string lastSavedFilePath = @"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\MyPicture.png"

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<FileResult> GetFileById(int id)
{
    //provides access to the physical file system, scoping all paths to a directory and its children
    IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(BASE_PATH);
    var fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(lastSavedFilePath);
    var fileStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
    this._contentTypeProvider.TryGetContentType(lastSavedFilePath, out var mimeType);
    return File(fileStream, mimeType, "ProfilePicture.png");
}
```

**Edit**
It turns out obtaining the file through the `PhysicalFileProvider` is not what I want to be async, I really want the Stream to be read async.

How Can I assure that when Calling my File Operation it will read my stream Async?

Comment: I do not think there is any benefit here. I believe if the design of that particular API warranted async they would have designed it as such. if you still want to have async you can always wrap in a `Task.Run`.

Comment: So suppose you are not using file provider. How will you read that file "async" then in your example (given that no actual reading happens in your code)?

Comment: @Nkosi Task Run would be beneficial,  while running pure normal async would free my thread,  if someone were to be loading say 100 profile picture thumbnails, I potentially will be blocking 100 threads during the time it takes to access the file system, alternatively I could have them freed while waiting to gain access to the disk

Comment: @Evk oops what I really want is to read from the stream async I’ll edit the question

Comment: Evk's answer is on point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PhysicalFileProvider` is perfectly capable of reading files async. `GetFileInfo` returns information about file, there is nothing that should be done async here. It's similar to `new FileInfo("path")`.

`CreateReadStream` obtains handle to target file, it's similar to `File.OpenRead()`. Again - nothing should be async here, and it's not whether you are using `PhysicalFileProvider` or not.

When you have file stream - you can read it asynchronously as usual (`ReadAsync` and so on), doesn't matter how you obtained it. In fact, `PhysicalFileProvider.CreateReadStream` even opens file with correct flags (`FileOptions.Asynchronous`), making that stream perfect for asynchronous access (and not good for non-async access).

In your case though you don't need to read that file stream yourself. You correctly return it with

```
return File(fileStream, mimeType, "ProfilePicture.png");
```

This will already read and write that file to http response stream *asynchronously* for you. That's because all `ActionResult`s, including `FileStreamResult` which you return, has `Task ExecuteAsync` method to actually execute that result. Asp.net will do `await yourFileResult.ExecuteAsync()` for you, and that `ExecuteAsync` will copy file stream to http response asynchronously.

So in short - just make your signature

```
public FileResult GetFileById(int id)
```

and you will be fine. What should be done asynchronously *is* done asynchrnously in this code already.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just wondering How can It Read Async when the await operator is not Supported before the call to the `File(fileStream, mimeType, "ProfilePicture.png")`

Comment: @johnny5 it is already read and written to response async as I said in answer, you don't need to await anything. `return File(stream)` returns `FileStreamResult` on which asp.net does `await result.ExecuteAsync()`. So asp.net will do that await for you.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense, do happen know of a document or a link to the source so I can read up more and fully understand how this operates?

Comment: Not really... I'm sure that's documented somewhere, but I don't know where. By that I mean specifically `ActionResult.ExecuteAsync`, because the rest is kind of common knowledge (not specific to asp.net core I mean).

Comment: Thank I’ll poke around the http pipeline document, I’ve been meaning to find that and where they dispose of the streams. I know they do it I just want to read up on it more so I have a clearer picture of everything

Comment: @johnny5: Everything is opensource, look for yourself. [ExecuteResultAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FileStreamResult.cs#L77) => https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs#L48 => https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/FileResultExecutorBase.cs#L322 90 seconds of search :)

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for finding that, and also thanks because now I Just found out you can search github code without downloading the source.

Comment: What about IFileInfo.Exists? Does not that have to make an actual access to the file system to verify? On my particular scenario, the file is actually set up through a virtual file share in IIS. So, a file is actually located on another server. Wouldn't IFileInfo.Exists be network-bound and take a lot of time to be completed?